# How to select on a series of dates (select with date dependent subquery)?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, subquery

Let's assume, there is a table in my PostgreSQL DB

```
 -----------+-----------------------------
 IP        | inet                        
 timestamp | timestamp                   
 ports     | integer REFERENCES other_table_does_not_matter                    
 hostname  | character varying
```

each IP is being checked every hour.

I want to group count(IP) i.e. summary daily unavailability by day, like below:

```
SELECT timestamp::date AS date, COUNT (DISTINCT IP) AS count 
FROM ip_check WHERE ports=9 AND ip NOT IN (SELECT IP FROM ip_check WHERE hostname <> '')
GROUP BY timestamp::date
ORDER BY timestamp::date ASC;
```

but there is an additional condition. I need to exclude IP that was available / reachable even for a short time (in my case hostname <> '' means, that IP was available):

```
... AND IP NOT IN (SELECT ... WHERE hostname <> '' AND DATE(timestamp)='2019-01-25')
```

In other words. I'd like to run, single SELECT (shown below) on a series of dates, and group results by day.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IP) 
FROM ip_check 
WHERE ports=9 AND DATE(timestamp)='2019-01-25' 
AND IP NOT IN 
    (SELECT IP 
     FROM ip_check 
     WHERE hostname <> '' AND DATE(timestamp)='2019-01-25');
```

Sample data:

```
 (ip;timestamp;ports;hostname)
 (1.1.1.1;2019-01-24 10:11;9;'')
 (1.1.1.1;2019-01-24 11:11;9;'hostA')
 (1.1.1.1;2019-01-24 1:11;9;'')
 (1.1.1.1;2019-01-24 2:11;9;'')
 (1.1.1.1;2019-01-24 3:11;9;'')
 (1.1.1.1;2019-01-24 4:11;9;'')
 (2.1.1.1;2019-01-24 10:11;9;'')
 (3.1.1.1;2019-01-24 10:11;9;'hostC')
 (1.1.1.1;2019-01-25 10:11;9;'')
 (1.1.1.1;2019-01-25 11:11;9;'')
 (1.1.1.1;2019-01-25 1:11;9;'hostA')
 (2.1.1.1;2019-01-25 10:11;9;'')
 (3.1.1.1;2019-01-25 10:11;9;'')
```

Desired output:

```
     data   | count
------------+-------
 2019-01-24 |  1
 2019-01-25 |  2
(2 rows)
```

Explanation :

- 2019-01-24 - only 1 IP (2.1.1.1) completely unavailable
- 2019-01-25 - 2 IP (2.1.1.1, 3.1.1.1) completely unavailable

Comment: Providing sample data and expected output would help others understanding this question.

Comment: Thanks, I've just added some sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exhibit the ip wich were *completely unavailable* for each day, you can use the below query :

```
SELECT ips.ip, dts.dt
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT ip FROM mytable) ips
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT timestamp::date dt FROM mytable) dts
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE ip = ips.ip AND timestamp::date = dts.dt AND hostname <> ''
)
```

The query works by generating a cartesian join between distincts IP and days, and uses a correlated subquery then filters in tuples that should be considered completely unavailable.

With your sample data, the query returns :

```
ip        dt
2.1.1.1   2019-01-24
2.1.1.1   2019-01-25
3.1.1.1   2019-01-25
```

---

To get the count of completely unavailable ips per day, we just turn this into an aggregated query :

```
SELECT dts.dt, COUNT(*)
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT ip FROM mytable) ips
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT timestamp::date dt FROM mytable) dts
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE ip = ips.ip AND timestamp::date = dts.dt AND hostname <> ''
)
GROUP BY dts.dt
```

Returns :

```
dt            count
2019-01-24    1
2019-01-25    2
```

**[Demo on db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2fae98bdd792476eabdc2d8841616477)**